# dynamic array of class

Tags: c++

I want to make a dynamic array of class objects. Though it is dynamic I have to calculate some size before initiating them; what strategy should I apply?

Answer (score 12):

Use the [**`std::vector`**](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/start) class from the standard library. That implements a strongly-typed dynamic array. It can be found inside the header `<vector>`.

Comment: can it store my custom data type defined in class?

Comment: @shak: Use `std::vector<my_class>` to store objects of your class.